# Boost::Xpressive::sregex uri pattern match

Tags: c++, regex, boost, xpressive

I've been searching and testing regex's to match all uris but I can't seem to find one that matches all or most of them. Lots of the ones I've tried throw a compile error. Does anyone have an Xpressive::sRegex compatible regex?

Comment: It throws compile error since it is likely that you include the delimiters, or not escaping the string properly.

Comment: I have this regex, does it look correct? "^([a-z0-9+.-]+):(?://(?:((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)@)?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)(?::(\d*))?(/(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?|(/?(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})+(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?)(?:\?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?(?:#((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?"

Comment: Ah ok I found this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252992/how-to-escape-a-string-for-use-in-boost-regex

Comment: I also have this one - is this correct? "(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+\.)*(\w*)\/([\w\d]+\/{0,1})+"

Comment: I wanted to mention that the above regex doesn't match anything and I'm also using the regex_search function for matching sub-strings in a string

Comment: Here are 8 regexp's for common things like e-mail addresses, IP addresses,  ... Number 6 in the list handles url's.

Comment: I think you missed the url but is this the right way of escaping? sregex::compile("(\?:ftp\|https\?:\/\/)\+(\?:\\S+\.)\+(\?:\\S\.)\+(\?:\S)\+");

Answer (score 0):

Something you can start from:

```
using namespace boost::xpressive;

static const sregex re = _b >> (s1 = +(~(set= ':', '/', '?', '#')))
                            >> as_xpr("://")
                            >> (s2 = *(~(set= '/', '?', '#')))
                            >> (s3 = *(~(set= '?', '#')))
                            >> !(as_xpr('?') >> (s4 = *(~(set='#'))))
                            >> !(as_xpr('#') >> (s5 = *_)) >> _b;
```