# Boost regexp match

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have such a regular expression

```
boost::regex isAgent
    ("Mozilla/\d[.]\d \(Windows NT \d[.]\d; (Win64; x64;|WOW64;)?(.*?)\) Gecko/\d{8} Firefox/\d\d[.]\d",
    boost::regex::perl);
if (boost::regex_search(auxAgent.c_str(), match, reg)){...}...
```

i know that in `auxAgent` i have exacly `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0`

on this page 
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?37em3 everything matches but not in boost, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the character `\` needs to be escaped. So if you want to escape anything, you need to do `\\`. That should fix the problem. Whenever you use the backslash in a string, you need to escape it like that. If you ever need to find it in a string with the regex, you'll need to search for it with `\\\\`.

Comment: Pawel is correct. To clarify, this means that your `isAgent` variable should be defined like so: `boost::regex isAgent ("Mozilla/\\d\\.\\d \\(Windows NT \\d\\.\\d; (Win64; x64;|WOW64;)?(.*?)\\) Gecko/\\d{8} Firefox/\\d\\d\\.\\d", boost::regex::perl);`

Answer (score 1):

I think Pawel Stawarz is correct. You should escape the backslashes. But here are all the characters you need to escape:

^ . $ | ( ) [ ] * + ? \ /

Replace \ with \\

and

Replace ? with \?

etc.

Source:
[How to escape a string for use in Boost Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252992/how-to-escape-a-string-for-use-in-boost-regex)