# Prevent interpretation of special characters in std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have the following function, written in C++11, that uses regular expressions from the standard `regex` module. As its name suggests, it determines whether the given string `str` is a number prefixed with the given `prefix`.

```
bool isPrefixedNumber(const std::string &prefix, const std::string &str) {
    std::regex re(prefix + "[[:digit:]]+"))
    return std::regex_match(str, re);
}
```

The problem is that I want `prefix` to be taken literally, i.e. I want

```
isPrefixedNumber("t.st", "tXst123")
```

to return `false`. Is there a way of constructing such a regular expression without the need to manually escape all occurrences of special characters in `prefix`? In another words, how to prevent the interpretation of special characters when passing a `std::string` into `std::regex`?

Note: The above function is just a simple illustration of my question. I need to prevent interpretation of strings in a much larger regular expression. I do not need another way of re-writing the function without regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`str.find(prefix) == 0` and `str.find_first_not_of("0123456789", prefix.size()) != std::string::npos` are the two things you want.

Whenever you have matching requirements, consider that a regex is actually a program that is parsed and executed at runtime. Put this in contrast with writing a few lines of C++ code and then decide which is better, but don't aim for regexes from the start.

Comment: Yes-- seems like this might be an X/Y problem.

Comment: I totally agree with you that this is a better approach for _this_ particular example. However, I need to prevent interpretation of strings in a much larger regular expression. I just came up with this simple example to illustrate my question. I will update the question to include this fact.

Comment: Okay. Still, when you say "don't interpret", it means verbatim use and therefore simple string matching, for which you should at least consider simple searching. That said, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252992/how-to-escape-a-string-for-use-in-boost-regex, it seems to answer your question.

Comment: I was kind of hoping there would be a built-in way of doing this so I don't have to do it manually. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: File a feature request for Boost, this is indeed something that is a reasonably common need and one that can easily be done wrong (e.g. by forgetting one of the many special characters).

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just match the two pieces separately, something along this general line:

```
std::string::size_type pos;

std::regex re(prefix + "[[:digit:]]+"));

return ((pos = str.find(prefix)) != std::string::npos) 
     && std::regex_match(str.substr(pos+prefix.size()), re));
```