# Regex escape in C++

Tags: regex, c++11

How can I regex-escape a dynamically inputted string.
I would like to surround it with actual regex code and then do matching, but I need all regex-special characters from the input escaped.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant Why not? Other languages have it and it could simplify my code.

Comment: if you escape all the regex metacharacters, then what you are really doing is plain string matching, and you don't need to use regexes at all.

Comment: As I said, I want to surround it with actual unescaped regex code.

Comment: Here is [almost what you need](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1253004/3832970).

Comment: Boost.Regex supports PCRE escaping via `\Q`...`\E`.

Comment: You will do the same as what is done in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Comment: does C++ support \Q\E  ?      http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html   I use a lot of Perl and that is my go to for literals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

`string LitString = R"(^(?:[1-9]\d*?|0)?(?:\.(?:\d*?[1-9]|0))?(?<=[\d])$)";`