# c++11/regex - search for exact string, escape

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11

Say you have a string which is provided by the user. It can contain any kind of character. Examples are:

```
std::string s1{"hello world");
std::string s1{".*");
std::string s1{"*{}97(}{.}}\\testing___just a --%#$%# literal%$#%^"};
...
```

Now I want to search in some text for occurrences of `>>` followed by the input string `s1` followed by `<<`. For this, I have the following code:

```
std::string input; // the input text
std::regex regex{">> " + s1 + " <<"};

if (std::regex_match(input, regex)) {
     // add logic here
}
```

This works fine if `s1` did not contain any special characters. However, if `s1` had some special characters, which are recognized by the regex engine, it doesn't work.

How can I escape `s1` such that `std::regex` considers it as a literal, and therefore does not interpret `s1`? In other words, the regex should be:

```
std::regex regex{">> " + ESCAPE(s1) + " <<"};
```

Is there a function like `ESCAPE()` in `std`?

**important** I simplified my question. In my real case, the regex is much more complex. As I am only having troubles with the fact the `s1` is interpreted, I left these details out.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using regular expressions? This can be done  with `string.find`

Comment: Why are you using _the input string_ (`s1`) as a regex?? Perhaps something like `std::regex Regex{">>*<<"};` would be better?

Comment: @Austin Brunkhorst Yes, I need regular expressions in my case. I simplified the question, as I am only struggling with the fact that the string is interpreted by the engine. In my real case, the regex is more complex.

Comment: @ForceBru There are two inputs: `s1` and some text. The string `s1` is used to dynamically construct the regex, which is used to search in the input text.

Comment: I would be tempted to construct a regex to extract the testable portion and then directly compare the string: `std::regex regex{">> (.*?) <<"}; ... if(match.str(1) == s1)...` could that work in your situation?

Comment: [This is related to "How to escape a string for use in Boost Regex"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252992/how-to-escape-a-string-for-use-in-boost-regex) since std::regex was largely based on boost::regex. You might consult that question for an answer.

Comment: It's a shame that C++ doesn't have a dedicated function for quoting/escaping a literal string into regexp (like [`Pattern.quote` in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) or [`Regex.Escape` in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape)).

Comment: @Wiktor I don't think this is a duplicate, since the other question is using boost but this one isn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to escape all special characters in the string with `\`. The most straightforward approach would be to use another expression to sanitize the input string before creating the expression `regex`.

```
// matches any characters that need to be escaped in RegEx
std::regex specialChars { R"([-[\]{}()*+?.,\^$|#\s])" };

std::string input = ">> "+ s1 +" <<"; 
std::string sanitized = std::regex_replace( input, specialChars, R"(\$&)" );

// "sanitized" can now safely be used in another expression
```

Comment: Do you really need to escape `^` here? And are you including all whitespace to deal with newlines or something? A little explanation would be useful. Also, don't you need to escape `\` too?

Comment: `^` is matched for the sake of completeness - obviously it will never match the start of a line with the preceding `>> `, but OP said the example is simplified. Can you elaborate on what you mean about whitespace and newlines?

Comment: Including `^` makes sense, but you've escaped it with a backslash. I'm curious why you've escaped it with a backslash in this situation. Also, you've included `\s`, which matches whitespace, but I'm not sure why you'd need that (maybe newline handling? I dunno; I can't remember how std::regex handles newlines and whether escaping them or not makes a difference). And in my previous comment I tried to say ``\`` should be included in `specialChars` too, but Markdown ate it.

Comment: Also about `#`, should that be escaped?

Comment: And `,`? Why should that be escaped?

Comment: You do not need to escape `,`, nor `#`, nor whitespace.

Comment: Why don't you escape backslash?

Comment: All one needs to escape with ` \ ` are these characters: `[\^$.|?*+(){}`. As [per](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html).

Comment: @c00000fd this list is unsufficient for e.g. `[({])}` input

Comment: `$&` is a "replacement" (placeholder for something to be substituted in) for the full match (all the matched text) for those wondering

Comment: Yep, none of these character lists (neither Austin Brunkhorst's nor
c00000fd's) is correct.